# Update function not working in web app mysql, php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update

I am creating a web app using html, php and a MySQL database. I want to update a value in the database using a drop down box. So you select the row you want to update by selecting the title of the project from the drop down box and then for every row that has that title the value of the "complete" column is updated. I have code but it is not updating my database.

Here is the code from the web page that populates the drop down box:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p>blah blah blah just testing</p>
            <?php

            $sql = "SELECT title FROM projects";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            echo "<select name='testTitle'>";
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<option value='" . $row['title'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select><br>";
             echo "<button type='submit' class='btn' name='markCom'>Mark project as complete</button> <button type='submit' class='btn' name='markNotCom'>Project was not completed :(</button>";

            ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code from my dbconnect.php file (which is including in my web app code):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hons');

if(isset($_POST['markCom'])){
    $testTitle = $_POST['testTitle'];
    $sql = "UPDATE projects SET complete=0 WHERE title = '$testTitle'";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
};
```

Comment: Where's your form tags?

Comment: That's what I was missing, I didn't include method = post in my form tag, thank you!